# How to control flow based on if user is logged in or not?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, passport-facebook

```
APP.GET('/', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) { if (isLoggedIn){res.render(index-authed) else { res.render(index)} });
```

how do i check what isLoggedIn returns? so i can handle flow like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass loggedIn status in your `req` object

in loggedIn function try adding following:

```
req.loggedIn = true;
```

and then in your next middleware function you can access `req.loggedIn`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question, in order to check what isLoggedIn returns, you can do that by a simple console.log like this:

```
console.log(isLoggedIn);
```

If you're using connect/express, it should return a Boolean.

Comment: would it be best to just use it as a regular function and not as middleware?

Comment: @rvncpn Since you're already checking it using the middleware, I wouldn't recommend using it again inside your callback.

Comment: so i should control the flow inside the middleware?

Comment: Correct. You can redirect the user elsewhere on the "isLoggedIn" function.